# SSIS import flat files to dynamic destination

Tags: ssis

I have a project I am working on where I need to import multiple csv files into the database.  I currently have 2 SQL servers (e.g. east coast and west coast) and I need to be able to split the data dynamically.  Each file has a client ID number which I can look up in a table and determine which server handles that client's data.  I have already figured out how to add that to my data flow tasks.  However, I now need to be able to split the data to the different servers.  I found a way to do this, but only for two servers.  We are considering adding multiple additional servers to split the workload. I need to be able to redirect the data to different servers dynamically.

For example:

The csv file has lines of data from a vendor for a dozen clients.  A few lines each are included for customers on each of four servers.  In my data flow I am importing the flat file and looking up the server for each line based on the client ID.  So essentially my data at this point looks like:

```
ClientID   ServerName   Col1   Col2   Col3...
------------------------------------------------------
12345      ServerA      data   data   data
54321      ServerB      data   data   data
12345      ServerA      data   data   data
78901      ServerC      data   data   data
54321      ServerB      data   data   data
76543      ServerD      data   data   data
```

I need to know how to make SSIS take each line and insert it into the specified table (the table name/structure is the same between servers) based on the ServerName column.

I'm thinking I probably need to use some kind of foreach loop and set the Server as a variable, but not sure how to implement this.

Any recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Huh. Interesting problem. The immediate problem I see is that the built in file parsing happens in a data flow so once you've begun parsing the data, it's too late to try and change the destination's connection manager. You could look at a Script Component and handle the database connectivity there. That's probably your least ugly approach.

Comment: Otherwise, I think I'd load the data into a single table on a dedicated server. I would then have an Execute SQL Task pull back the distinct list of Servers and, much as you've outlined, use a ForEach enumerator to shred that list. For each server found, I'd update my destination Connection Manager with the ServerName. Then my Data Flow would select from my staging table with a filter against the current server name. You'd effectively process the file twice so for very large sets of data, this many be untenable but it'd save you from scripting

Answer (score -1):

If everything else in the connection string is the same except serverName, then do as follows:

1: Create an execute sql task to create the initial select.  Send the result set to a ResultSet variable of type Object.  Also set the sql task result set type as "Full Result Set".

2: Push that into a forEach Loop, and map your 5 columns into SSIS variables, so one for each (ClientID, ServerName, etc).

3: Create a connection manager to your server, and open up the Expression tab.  Select "Connection String" and set it to evaluate to "YourHost/{user:ServerName}/DatabaseName:Port.. etc".  Basically just copy and paste what the connection string is after you've verified the connection is fine, and replace the servername portion.

4:Create another sql task, this time it will just be an insert statement with the values being parameterized (?,?,?,?,?) and map your variables to the parameters.

That should do it.  If you need more guidance, let me know.  I've had to do all kinds of crazy stuff like this in SSIS!

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted... I implemented it and it works.